# D3 and React-Native

Tags: react-native, d3.js

Does react-native support D3 library/npm modules like d3-select?

For me, it is throwing error - querySelectionAll(selection) undefined.

It is working fine on reactJS but not on react-native.

Please help.Totally Stuck.

Comment: D3 itself works natively with the browser. React Native does not include browser APIs because it's used to make smartphone applications...

Comment: if you want to use d3 library with react native, you can look around [this great tutorial](https://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/) and [these examples on github](https://github.com/mdvacca/rn-d3-art-charts)

Comment: I guess react-native does not have DOM so you can't do querySelectionAll in react-native

Answer (score 6):

Check this out: https://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/

Basically you can use ART (of react-native) and D3 together to create lovely graphs. I'm not sure exactly what the limitations are, but it seems like the best option for now.

Comment: that example works with a warning on Android and does not work on iOs

Comment: Note that the ART library was removed from Expo, and they now recommend Svg.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install d3 —-save` , `npm install d3-shape —-save` and `npm install art —-save`

These are 3 packages for making D3 shapes and utilizing them.
[Here](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/animated-charts-in-react-native-using-d3-and-art-21cd9ccf6c58) in this article, writer uses these packages.

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe you cannot use d3-select in react-native as it meant to target DOM nodes, which only available in web.

Second, you can use other D3 library, just make sure you do the import correctly. For example, if you want to use d3-ease, do this:

```
import * as D3Ease from "d3-ease";
```

instead of this

```
import D3Ease from "d3-ease";
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
const interpolatedWidth = D3Ease.easePolyIn(value, 4.0);
```